# Compiling Boost with VS2013

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile the Boost Calc6 example here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc6/

Normally, this goes off without a hitch on my Mac using Xcode. At present, I am on a PC using VS2013. I've added a couple things to the standard setup you get when creating a Win32 Console Application. Normally, it sets you up with a ProjectTitle.cpp, and stdafx.cpp (which just has #include "stdafx.h" inside).

Here is what the file containing "main" within the Calc example looks like

```
#include "calc6.hpp"
#include "stdafx.h" /* I ADDED THIS, AS IT COMES AS BOILERPLATE WITH VS PROJECT

template <typename Grammar>
bool compile(Grammar const& calc, std::string const& expr)

{
    using ascii::space;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = expr.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = expr.end();
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, space);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        return false;
    }
}

struct var_printer
{
    var_printer(std::vector<int> const& stack)
    : stack(stack)
    {
    }

    template <typename String, typename Data>
    void operator()(String const& s, Data const& data)
    {
        std::cout << "    " << s << ": " << stack[data] << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<int> const& stack;
};

int
_tmain() // I CHANGED THIS FROM MAIN TO _TMAIN
{
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Expression parser...\n\n";
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Type some statements... ";
    std::cout << "Then type period ('.') to compile, run and print results\n\n";

    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef statement<iterator_type> statement;

    vmachine mach;                  //  Our virtual machine
    std::vector<int> code;          //  Our VM code
    statement calc(code);           //  Our grammar

    std::string str;
    std::string program;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == '.')
            break;
        program += str;
    }

    if (::compile(calc, program))
    {
        mach.execute(code, calc.nvars);

        std::cout << "Results------------------\n\n";
        calc.vars.for_each(var_printer(mach.get_stack()));
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Noticed I added

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

and changed main to

```
_tmain()
```

All the other .cpp and .hpp files are copied exactly as is. At this point, I get: (apologies for the bad error message editing)

```
  Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
statement<class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct
std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::statement<class
std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct
std::_Simple_types<char> > > >(class std::vector<int,class
std::allocator<int> > &)" 
(??0?$statement@V?$_String_const_iterator@V
$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@@QAE@AAV?$vector@HV
$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) 
referenced in function _wmain
c:\Users\housegroup\documents\visual studio2013\Projects\example\example\calc6.obj example
```

when I uncomment

```
statement calc(code)
```

in _tmain(). Otherwise, It at least compiles when I comment it out (for instance, if i left all of _tmain() blank.

Please help, I almost never use Visual Studio :(

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and re-adding all the header files to the Header Files folder fixed this. Previously, I had it all within the Source Files folder.